# Warning: unlink(): The local filesystem is readonly, unlink failed

Tags: wordpress, macos, google-app-engine, mamp

After upgrading to GoogleAppEngineLauncher 1.9.20.242 I can no longer seem to do upgrades on my local machine in WordPress.

```
Downloading https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.3.1.1.zip…

Warning: unlink(): The local filesystem is readonly, unlink failed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/googleappengine/coworking-radolfzell.de/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 453

Download failed. Could not open connection to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/googleappengine/coworking-radolfzell.de/wordpress/wp-content/tmp/akismet5.tmp via fopen()
```

I've tried to adjust permissions in various ways with no success, this is how the wp-content folder looks like:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nick  admin   30 Apr 25  2014 index.php
drwxrwxrwx  12 nick  admin  408 Apr 28  2014 languages
drwxrwxrwx   9 nick  admin  306 Feb 27 00:11 plugins
drwxrwxrwx   6 nick  admin  204 Feb 20 16:53 themes
drwxrwxrwx   8 nick  admin  272 May 13 12:38 tmp
drwxrwxrwx   2 nick  admin   68 Feb 27 00:11 upgrade
drwxrwxrwx   4 nick  admin  136 Apr 25  2014 uploads
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here? Looks like a bug in GoogleAppEngineLauncher to me as it was working fine before the latest update and I didn't make any changes to the local installation which I'm pretty sure about, because it's all under version control.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems to be a bug in more recent releases of  GoogleAppEngineLauncher. In the meantime I upgraded to 1.9.23, but still get the same `filesystem is readonly` error.

When I use MAMP instead of GoogleAppEngineLauncher's web server the plugin and core updates work just fine. To easily circumvent the site URLs which in my case was

```
http://localhost:9080/
```

Just add the following 2 lines to your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8888/path/to/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8888/path/to/wordpress');
```

assuming that you use MAMP's default port 8888. Now call your WordPress backend via http://localhost:8888/path/to/wordpress and you should be able to do your updates without any error messages.

Important: Don't forget to remove or comment-out the 2 lines before you deploy your updates to app engine.